# How can I break the link of git config <url>.insteadOf <url>

Tags: git, url, config

I set my url to other url with git config .insteadOf , and now I want to break the link of it. But I don't know how to do that and I can't find it at the reference page.

Answer (score 20):

You can remove the section [url "git@github.com"] with:

```
git config --global --remove-section url."git@github.com"
```

That is safer than trying to edit manually the git config file.

Reference page: [`git config#--remove-section`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt---remove-section).

Comment: VonC's git answers don't follow a coding convention.  They *are* the coding convention.

Comment: @Nathanmajicvr.com Thank you for your kind words, but I would still double-check those answers!

Comment: I'm sure (some of) the other upvoters checked them.  So your fix definitely worked in most environments

Our king had a good week, even compared to the other "fastest horses" on this site: https://imgur.com/a/5HkINis

Answer (score 8):

All your git config changes go to `~/.gitconfig`, so you should be able to edit it, the relevant part looks like this:

```
[url "git@github.com"]
        insteadOf = gh
```

so, maybe try removing these lines?